# How to start a non-blocking process within a multiprocess in Python 3

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a script to monitor a SNS for Live video.

The main program creates several multiprocess and put them into a pool. These multiprocess monitor different SNS accounts. Once live video is found, another process is started to record the video, so the script can continue monitor other accounts.

The problem is "daemonic processes are not allowed to have children".

How should I achieve what I want to do? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `threading` or `async` instead

Comment: Do you mean multiprocessing async? Does it work within a daemonic process?

Comment: You could use any of those from the daemonic process I think. I mean to have an async loop inside the process or to have child threads instead.

Comment: Excuse me I learn Python through coding and Googling. I don't know the "async" you refer to. Is it asyncio? May you please give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, i am refering to `asyncio`, sorry for the missnaming.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know asyncio. I have learned this new thing. Although I have found out threading should be the solution instead of asyncio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use threading within multiprocessing daemon process